# How to calculate duplicate events ? Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

**collected data :**

I have a custom dimension called **advertisingId** with hit-scope , which is sent along with the event actions, here is an example of the collected data:

```
 #      action       |    advertisinId   

 1      install           30                
 2      install           10
 3      install           30
 4      install           10
 5      install           40
 6      install           50
```

**requested metrics :**

in google analytics i would like to build two metrics:

1. returning event : event who has advertisingId which is already associated to previous event.
2. unique event : an event who has advertisingId which is not associated to any previous event.

**processes data example :**

so according to the above collected data , here is the how the processes data should be:

```
 #      action       |    advertisinId   | returningEvent 

 1      install           30                 no. there is no previous event who has the same advertisingId
 2      install           10                 no. there is no previous event who has the same advertisinId
 3      install           30                 yes. because event #1 has the same advertisingId
 4      install           10                 yes. because event #2 has the same advertisingId
 5      install           40                 no. unique advertisingId
 6      install           50                 no. unique advertisinId
```

**Final Report :**
accordig to the processes data i need to build the following report:

```
action     |   unique event   |  returningEvent
 install        4                     2
```

How could i build that, what custom metrics i should build and configure ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your 'Action' field here is actually 'Event Action', you should already be able to extract this data from Google Analytics. I can't think of a way to get it as a calculated metric, but you can certainly get the volumes yourself.

Create a Flat Table Custom Report with Metric 'Total Events', and Dimensions 'Event Action' and 'advertisingID'.

- **Unique Events** (as you defined above) is equal to the number of rows in the report.
- **Returning Events** (as you defined above) is equal to the sum of 'Total Events' in the report, minus the **Unique Events** figure defined above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the problem that "unique events" is the count of unique events relative to session. i need to count unique events in relative to all inserted data.

Comment: I know. I'm not suggesting that you use the Unique Events metric provided by Google Analytics, I'm explaining how to define the metrics that you explained above.

Comment: @david I'm pretty sure this is the answer to your question.